# Accessing prototype parent

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototype, this

Let's say I have a `Posts` class.

I can do:

```
Posts.prototype.foo = function () {
  console.log(this);
}
```

And when I call `post1.foo()` (with `post1` being an instance of the `Posts` class), the `this` outputted by the console will be equal to `post1`.

Now consider the following scenario:

```
Posts.prototype.baz = {
  foo: function () {
   console.log(this);
  },
  bar: [1,2,3,4]
}
```

Now when I do `post1.baz.foo()`, the value of `this` is no longer `post1`, but instead `{foo: ..., bar: ...}`.

My question is: in that second scenario, how can I access `post1` from within `foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're bumping up against an interesting problem. What you're doing is not a common pattern in Javascript (assigning a nested object to the prototype), and on the surface it looks like it should work.

Javascript `this` is resolved in two ways. If you're making a function instantiated with `new`, `this` becomes a reference to that instantiated object (as you know).

However, `this` can also resolve to the parent **object**. That is, this code will log `'bar'`:

```
var obj = {
    prop: 'bar',
    log: function() { console.log( this.prop ); }
};
obj.log();
```

Because `this` is referencing the object the function is inside. That's what's happening in your case. The scope is being resolved earlier than you want.

Aside: If the function isn't nested inside an object, and you don't use `new`, `this` will become the global object (`window` in the browser).

The proper way to do this is probably in the constructor for Posts, where you can set `this.whatever` and bind it to the instance. This method is most commonly used for "private" variables, but can also be useful when you need to add computed data to your class, or in your case, declare specific scope.

```
function Posts() {
    var self = this;

    this.baz = {
        foo: function () {
            console.log(self);
        },
        bar: [1,2,3,4]
    }
}
```

You could also do:

```
    ...
    this.baz = {
        foo: function () {
            console.log(this);
        }.bind(this),
```

You may want to take a closer look at why you need a nested object on the class prototype. Can you break it down into all flat prototype methods? Is it data that doesn't need to be instantiated on every single class instance, and could be pulled out somewhere else?

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I will probably just break it down into flat prototype methods. I actually thought doing it this way would be "cleaner" since I'm not polluting the class' namespace as much. But then I bumped into this issue…

Comment: Also, I can't modify the `Posts` class itself, so I guess I couldn't use your other solutions.

Comment: Depending on your use case, another potential solution is to make a wrapping class (that you control) that has a post inside it. Modifying someone else's prototype often causes problems historically.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a "this" keyword, the object to which it get bounded depends on the call site. Only on the call site. Here's a deeper discussion [you don't know js](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md). I strongly suggest you to read that. However, if you let me over simplify it, consider it this way:

whenever you execute a function, it is roughly as if you were doing the following:

```
//default binding
fn() ~ fn.call(window)
// the default binding of this, is window, or undefined in strict mode.
```

you can however, call the function, with a

```
//implicit binding
obj.fn() ~ fn.call(ojb) 
// in this case you are implicitly binding this as the obj
```

Or if you want to be explicit, use `call` or `apply`:

```
//explicit bining
fn.call(obj)  
//this is explicitly binding obj as this.
```

The precedence of those is explicit > implicit > default.

In your case, you are running `post1.baz.foo()`: your call site is `.baz`. for rule 2, you are binding `this` to `baz`. What you want is to go explicit and call `post1.baz.foo.call(post1);`.

*humble opinion follows*

That is really ugly tho, so I feel your pain. The reason it is so complex, is because you are working *against the grain* of the language. It is probably because you are trying to do inheritance in the java way.

and finally,there's one more binding, but avoid it: `new`. If you can, never ever use new. JS is not java, and the behavior of new is very confusing. If you want to instantiate new objects, use Object.create.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out that post. I think I mostly understand the issue with the call site, I just thought there might've been some clever syntaxic workaround somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change how you call this method, you could access `this` inside `baz`. For example:

```
post1.baz.foo.call(post1);
```

Will make `this` inside your `foo` function instance of Posts class and will `console.log` correct object.

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/bLdop1hy/)